# How to loop through a directory that includes files and hidden files

Tags: bash, for-loop, if-statement, arguments

I am trying to compare a given file and compare it to a directory's files to see if any of the files within the directory are newer than the file given. I want to go through all files in the given directory including hidden files. I cannot figure out how.

I've tried changing "direct"/*; to "direct"/.* but it will only include the hidden files then but not all of the other files that are within the given directory.

```
inputfile=$1 
direct=$2  
for file in "$direct"/*; do
if [[ $file -nt $inputfile ]] 
then
echo $(stat $file | grep Modify | cut -d' ' -f2,3) #formatting
fi
done
```

Comment: 1. Use `find` instead of `for i in *`, use `-type f` and `-newer "$inputfile"`. Remember to `-maxdepth`. 2. `stat` has option to modify output `--printf`. Use it to print modification date only, remove the filtering. 3. With that in mind use `-exec stat` option with `find` and replace your whole script with a single command.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `find` command to achieved this as per this other answer: [Delete files older than specific file](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/186776/delete-files-older-than-specific-file)

```
inputfile=$1 
direct=$2 
find $direct/ -type f ! -newer $inputfile
```